# PHP Parse SOAP envelope to XML

Tags: php, soap, xml-parsing

I been at this all day and feel like I'm getting nowhere, I need to get this to display as an xml like how it is on this page http://admin.stock.imdfulfilment.com/api/service.asmx/GetCouriers. Yet the following code

```
<?
try
{
    $soap_url = 'http://admin.stock.imdfulfilment.com/api/service.asmx?wsdl';
    $client = new SoapClient($soap_url, array(
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions'=>true,
                'GetCouriersResult' => 'xml')
            );

    $client->GetCouriers();
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($client->__getLastResponse());
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
    foreach($xml->xpath('//soap:Envelope') as $item) {
        echo "$item\n\n";
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   print_r($e);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns doubly encoded XML, I have no idea why someone thought that a Good Idea (perhaps someone who doesn't want to bother with updating their wsdl):

```
$soap_url = 'http://admin.stock.imdfulfilment.com/api/service.asmx?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($soap_url, array(
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions'=>true,
            'GetCouriersResult' => 'xml')
        );

$result = $client->GetCouriers();
echo $result->GetCouriersResult->any;
//or you can load it in DOM or simpleXML if you need to read it;
$the_response_should_have_been = new simpleXMLElement($result->GetCouriersResult->any);
```